# What would be the best approach to search user by the name?

Tags: javascript, sql, html, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure that should accept few different parameters. Based on parameters query will return desired results. However, there is one filter that I'm not 100% sure what would be the best option to choose. Here is example:

```js
$('#frm_filterby').on('change', changeAttr);

function changeAttr() {
  var elementVal = $(this).val();
  $("#frm_search").removeAttr('pattern maxlength title');

  switch (elementVal) {
    case "1":
      $("#frm_search").attr({
        "type": "text",
        "placeholder": "Example: tcook56",
        "pattern": "[a-z0-9_-]{0,50}$",
        "title": "User name allows alphanumeric (lowercase only) characters, underscore, dash - no other special characters",
        "maxlength": "50",
        "disabled": false,
        "required": true
      }).val("");
      break;
    case "2":
      $("#frm_search").attr({
        "type": "email",
        "placeholder": "example@gmail.com",
        "title": "Enter email address",
        "maxlength": "80",
        "disabled": false,
        "required": true
      }).val("");
      break;
    case "3":
      $("#frm_search").attr({
        "type": "search",
        "placeholder": "(Last, First)",
        "pattern": "[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z' .,-]{0,100}$",
        "title": "A-Z, space, dash, apostrophe, period, comma - no other special characters",
        "maxlength": "100",
        "disabled": false,
        "required": true
      }).val("");
      break;
    default:
      $("#frm_search").attr({
        "type": "text",
        "placeholder": "Select Search Criteria",
        "disabled": true,
        "required": false
      }).val("");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form name="frmFind" id="frmFind">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <select class="form-control" name="frm_status" id="frm_status" required>
        <option value="">--Status--</option>
        <option value="2">All</option>
        <option value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="0">InActive</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <select class="form-control" name="frm_filterby" id="frm_filterby" required>
        <option value="">--Search By--</option>
        <option value="1">Username</option>
        <option value="2">Email</option>
        <option value="3">Name</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control find-search" name="frm_search" id="frm_search" placeholder="Select Search Criteria" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
                        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="alert message-submit"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In example above you can see what filters they can choose and everything but the name is kind of messy in my opinion. My idea was to have them enter Just first or last or combination of first and last separated by comma. Problem is that we allow comma in last and first name so that would cause confusion. Let's say if someone has last name `Doe, Junior` in that case my code would assume that `Doe` is last name and `Junior` is first name. I'm wondering what would be a good option for this case? Also here is my SQL search query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchUsers] 
    @Status INT = NULL,
    @FilterBy INT = NULL,
    @Username VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Email VARCHAR(80) = NULL,
    @LastName VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @FirstName VARCHAR(50) = NULL   
AS
    SELECT A.FirstName, A.LastName, A.Middle, A.Email,
        A.UserStatus, A.UserName, A.Password M.Name AS Position
    FROM Accounts AS A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Master AS M
            ON M.Tblid = 'POSITION'
            AND M.Code = A.Position
    WHERE A.IsUser = 1
        AND
        (
            ((@Status = 0 OR @Status = 1) AND A.UserStatus = @Status)
            OR
            (@Status = 2 AND 1 = 1)
        )
        AND
        (
            (@FilterBy = 1 AND A.UserName = @Username)
            OR
            (@FilterBy = 2 AND A.Email = @Email)
            OR
            (
            @FilterBy = 3 
            AND
            A.LastName LIKE 
                CASE WHEN Len(@LastName) > 0 THEN '%' + LastName + '%'
                ELSE '%' 
                END
            AND
            A.FirstName LIKE 
                CASE WHEN Len(@FirstName) > 0 THEN '%' + @FirstName + '%'
                ELSE '%'
                END 
            )
        )
    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Code above works fine when I enter some values for both First and Last name. In case when I enter for example just Last name `Doe` query will return all records from the table. Is there a good way to solve this problem and accommodate users to have an option to search for bot first and last name but at the same time give them an option to search only for one either last or first?

Comment: are you using asp.net to access your sql db?

Comment: @imBlue I use ColdFusion 2016.

Comment: if you allow commas then you can use replace function in SQL to change the comma or any other key and then use javascript to replace it back when you are about to display it on front end.

Comment: @imBlue Can you provide example about your suggestion/solution?

Comment: sure! give me a few mins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query, you have this

```
A.LastName LIKE 
            CASE WHEN Len(@LastName) > 0 
            THEN '%' + LastName + '%'
            ELSE '%' 
            END
        AND
```

you need to set the parameter instead of the column

```
CASE WHEN Len(@LastName) > 0 THEN '%' + **@LastName** + '%'
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: oof I did not see this myself good catch, this is probably the fix op is looking for.